# How to struct a Gantt Chart using flex divs using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm structuring a Gantt Chart component using CSS and HTML.

The below image illustrate the necessary user viewing interactions:

[image]

The red boundaries is the current user view. The desired scrolling behaviour is as follows:

a) The tasks are must be scrolled vertically and horizontally as data can be out of viewable area.

b) When scrolling horizontally, the scale must be scrolled in sync (the scale will have date/time tags).

c) When scrolling horizontally, the left title boxes must remain fixed on the left, not scrolling together.

d) When scrolling vertically, the scale must remain fixed at the top.

e) When scrolling vertically, the titles boxes scrolls together with taks, keeping in sync view.

Here is what've tried so far with no success.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
}

.areas {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.leftarea {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ababab;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.rightarea {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.titlecard {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 30px;
  background-color: #435543;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
}

.scale {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  background-color: #433777;
}

.scaletick {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.tasks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #393984;
  height: 100%;
}

.taskcard {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.taskcard1 {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.taskcard2 {
  width: 550px;
  margin-left: 230px;
}

.taskcard3 {
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.taskcard4 {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.taskcard5 {
  width: 350px;
  margin-left: 400px;
}

.taskcard6 {
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 90px;
}

.taskcard7 {
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: 230px;
}

.taskcard8 {
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.taskcard9 {
  width: 60px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.taskcard10 {
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="areas">
    <div class="leftarea">
      <div class="titlecard">
        Title 1
      </div>
      <div class="titlecard">
        Title 2
      </div>
      <div class="titlecard">
        Title 3
      </div>
      <div class="titlecard">
        Title 4
      </div>
      <div class="titlecard">
        Title 5
      </div>
      <div class="titlecard">
        Title 6
      </div>
      <div class="titlecard">
        Title 7
      </div>
      <div class="titlecard">
        Title 8
      </div>
      <div class="titlecard">
        Title 9
      </div>
      <div class="titlecard">
        Title 10
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightarea">
      <div class="scale">
        <div class="scaletick">
          01/01/2000
        </div>
        <div class="scaletick">
          02/01/2000
        </div>
        <div class="scaletick">
          03/01/2000
        </div>
        <div class="scaletick">
          04/01/2000
        </div>
        <div class="scaletick">
          05/01/2000
        </div>
        <div class="scaletick">
          06/01/2000
        </div>
        <div class="scaletick">
          07/01/2000
        </div>
        <div class="scaletick">
          08/01/2000
        </div>
        <div class="scaletick">
          09/01/2000
        </div>
        <div class="scaletick">
          10/01/2000
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tasks">
        <div class="taskcard taskcard1">
          Task 1
        </div>
        <div class="taskcard taskcard2">
          Task 2
        </div>
        <div class="taskcard taskcard3">
          Task 3
        </div>
        <div class="taskcard taskcard4">
          Task 4
        </div>
        <div class="taskcard taskcard5">
          Task 5
        </div>
        <div class="taskcard taskcard5">
          Task 6
        </div>
        <div class="taskcard taskcard7">
          Task 7
        </div>
        <div class="taskcard taskcard8">
          Task 8
        </div>
        <div class="taskcard taskcard9">
          Task 9
        </div>
        <div class="taskcard taskcard10">
          Task 10
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the necessary behaviour?

Comment: So the problem is with the scrolling, right?

Comment: Both vertical and horizontal keeping scale header and left cards in place